# Swipe in ViewPager2 not working while nested ScrollView is fling-scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager2

I have a `ViewPager2` with default horizontal swipe-navigaton. Each "page" has a `ScrollView` so that content can be scrolled vertically. Normally this works well: When the touch movement starts horizontally it is handled by the `ViewPager`, when it starts vertically it is handled by the `ScrollView`.

However after a vertical fling gesture, while the `ScrollView` is scrolling on its own, *any* touch movement is handled by the `ScrollView`, whether it starts horizontally or vertically. So users first have to stop the fling before they can swipe to the next page. **How can I change this?**

In the Gmail app, when swiping between mails, the behaviour is as I expect it.

Comment: This behavior is baked into [ScrollViews touch event](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java#688) and I don't see an easy way to modify it. After touch down while flinging scrollview tries to "resume" the touch event so it immediately calls `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` and doesn't respect touch slope anymore so even if you somehow prevented propagation of interception disallowance it leaves ugly issue of scrollview scrolling even if you perform a few pixel worth of vertical move during following "horizontal" scroll.

Comment: @Pawel, yes I also think it won't be so easy. Didn't examine the ScrollView source before but suppose I must if no one knows a solution right away. In the GMail app it works as I want it when swiping between mails, any idea how it's done there?

Comment: I can't tell exactly how it's made but you can notice it doesn't behave like a scrollview - if you stop a fling it will select the text and won't scroll until touch slop is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a simple solution. I override `onInterceptTouchEvent` of a parent view of the ViewPager2, there on `ACTION_DOWN`, I stop the fling of the ScrollView with `fling(0)`.